# magento 404 not found

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am new in magento . I fallow its tutorial and create my first module.
but it's returns 404 not found:

config.xml file is below:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>

</config>
```

and Magento_Helloworld.xml is:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and the controller is :

```
class Magentotutorial_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        die( 'Hello Index!');
    }

}
```

now I try

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/helloworld/index/index
```

and see 404 page! where is the problem?

I cleared cache from admin!

Comment: did you module listed in `system->configuration tab advanced`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your xml files should looks like this:
'app/etc/modules/Magentotutorial_Helloworld.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

'app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/config.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

P.S. controller should be in the 'app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers/' directory

Comment: Not working!! its controller is in the 'controllers' directory

Comment: Did you checked the logs (php error log, exception.log, system.log), maybe you have an error in other place?

Comment: oops! i am a beginner ! I created  the 'local'  directory in an other folder!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ a2enmod rewrite
$ service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Please explain your solution a little more so that future searchers can perhaps apply it to their situation.